# formik validation yup React

Tags: validation, formik, yup

I have a form and I'm validating it. But I need not only these rules to be entered in the "USERNAME" field, but also: so that there must be letters and numbers. And it turns out that username can be just +100, which does not suit me

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    email: Yup.string()
      .email("Введите верный email")
      .required("Обязательное поле"),
    username: Yup.string()
      .min(4, "Слишком короткое имя")
      .max(50, "Слишком длинное имя")

      .required("Обязательное поле"),
    password: Yup.string()
      .min(4, "Слишком короткий пароль")
      .max(50, "Слишком длинный пароль")
      .required("Обязательное поле"),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string()
      .oneOf([Yup.ref("password")], "Пароли не совпадают")
      .required("Обязательно"),
  });
```

yup formik validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `USERNAME` and `username` are not the same, cases must match. By matching case you will solve the problem with max/min lenght.

Second, you can add `.matches()` method to chain like

```
username: Yup.string()
      .min(4, "Слишком короткое имя")
      .max(50, "Слишком длинное имя")
      .matches(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/, 'Недопустимые символы')
```

Good luck.